# Date not being stored in database from .xlsx sheet in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpexcel

I have a page to save an excel sheet records to the database. The records are being stored same way as they are provided in excel sheet other than "date of birth" column.
The "Date of Birth" column saves only for the second record being uploaded from excel sheet. I had been searching a lot on this but not found the exact reason for it.

Here is my complete code ,

```
<?php include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ; 
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
?>
<?php
$scsmsg         =   "" ;
$errmsg         =   "" ;






if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    extract($_POST);
    //$moduleId =    mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($module_id)));die;
                    if(empty($_FILES['bulk_file']['name']))
                    {
                           $errmsg .= 'Please Choose File.<br>';

                    }
                    if(!empty($_FILES['bulk_file']['name']))
                    {

                    $extensions = array('.xlsx');

                    $valid_extensions = '.xlsx';
                    $extension = strrchr($_FILES['bulk_file']['name'], '.');
                    if (!in_array($extension, $extensions))
                    {
                    $errmsg .="Wrong files format , alowed Extension only".$valid_extensions.""."<br>";
                    } 
                    }


            if($errmsg  ==  "")                 
            {       
                                $created            =    date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
                                $register_date          =    date("Y-m-d");
                                $created_by         =    $_SESSION['session_admin_id'] ;


                                $bulk_file  =   $_FILES['bulk_file']['name'];
                                if(!empty($bulk_file))
                {                       
                                 $tmp_name=$_FILES['bulk_file']['tmp_name'];                   
                                 $bulk_file=$_FILES['bulk_file']['name'];                    
                                 $file_name     =   $bulk_file;
                                 //$file=$file_name.".csv";                  
                                 $inputFileName = "uploads/user/$file_name";                     
                                 $file_sucess=move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$inputFileName); 







                                //$inputFileName = 'format.xlsx'; 
                            try {
                                $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
                            } catch(Exception $e) 
                            {
                                die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
                            }
                        $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
                        $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet


                        for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
                        {
                            $salutation     =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
                            $sbiempid   =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]); 
                            $branch =   trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);
                            $middlename     =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]); 
                            $firstname  =   trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]);
                            $lastname   =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["F"]); 
                            $dateofbirth    =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]);   
                          $dateInput = explode('-',$dateofbirth);
              $dob = $dateInput[2].'-'.$dateInput[1].'-'.$dateInput[0];
           // $dob ="19".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateofbirth)); 
                    //var_dump($dob);
         //print_r($dob);
                            $mobileno   =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["H"]); 
                            $email  =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["I"]);
                            $city   =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["J"]);    
                            $state          =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["K"]);
                            $designation            =    trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["L"]);


                            $corporate_user_sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from  tbl_corporate where id='$created_by'"));
                            $pre_define_day=$corporate_user_sql['pre_defined_day'];

                                $dataQuestion   =   array("type"=>"3","salutation"=>$salutation, "employee_id"=>$sbiempid, "branch"=>$branch, "middle_name"=>$middlename, "first_name"=>$firstname, "last_name"=>$lastname, "dob"=> $dob, "mobile"=>$mobileno, "email"=>$email, "city"=>$city,"state"=>$state,"designation"=>$designation,"created_on"=>$created, "created_by"=>$created_by,"status"=>"0","register_date"=>$register_date,"request_updated_day"=>$pre_define_day,"registration_type"=>"1");


                                $db->query_insert("tbl_user", $dataQuestion);
                                $question_id = mysql_insert_id();
                                $raw_password=uniqid().$question_id;
                                $md5_pass=md5(uniqid().$question_id);

                                        $dataOption1    =   array("registration_id"=>$sbiempid."_".$question_id,"password"=>$md5_pass,"raw_password"=>$raw_password);
                                        $db->query_update("tbl_user", $dataOption1,"id=$question_id");      
                        }

                }
                    $scsmsg         =   "<b>Record inserted Successfully</b>";

            }
}
?>
<div class="container pagecontainer">
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">
      <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">
        <?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Upload User</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="column col-sm-offset-0">
<?php
                if($scsmsg!="")
                {
                    echo "<div class='success'>".ucwords($scsmsg)."</div>";
                }
                if($errmsg!="")
                {
                    echo "<div class='error'>".ucwords($errmsg)."</div>";
                }
                echo "<div id='error'></div>";
            ?>            
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">



               <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Select FIle:</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-9">

                    <input type="file" name="bulk_file" class="form-control" required=""  >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">
                    <a href="CandidateProfileUploadInformation.xlsx" class="btn btn-info">Download Format</a></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-9 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save</button>
                    <button type="reset" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='quizList.php';" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
                    <button type="reset" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Go Back</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
  </div>
</div>
<?php include 'blocks/footerInc.php'; ?>
```

May I  know where am I doing wrong in this as rest of the data fields are being posted semantically. This stores date of birth only for the second record in the excel sheet and for rest rows date of birth are being saved as 0000-00-00.
Any suggestion and help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the data from the excel spreadsheet into your array? Are you getting it formatted? or as raw cell data?

Comment: If you're getting raw data, then the date value is likely to be a floating point number containing the MS Excel serialized timestamp value for the date

Comment: Thanks for response but I am just taking date here in data loop and inserting it into database. As I have written in other answer's comment when doing a var_dump($dob), it outputs 
string(8) "90-15-03"

Comment: and what I filled in the excel is 15-03-1990. And it ultimately gets stored in databse as 1990-03-15 but only for the second record skipping the third record and first record only for $dob

Comment: Is this an actual MS Excel xls/xlsx file? Or is it  csv file? How are you getting the data from the file into your PHP array?

Comment: Internally, MS Excel stores dates as a floating point timestamp value, not as a formatted string.

Comment: it is a '.xlsx' file. I have made this and kept for bulk uploading sample . This whole thing is working for bulk uploading of users

Comment: and if ms-excel stores date as floating point timestamp, then how my second record's dob is getting perfectly stored up in database. I just posted my entire code. Please, let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: This code is such a mess…

Comment: @slick Yes mate I agree on that but have just begun with PHP. my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you don't request formatted values when you build the array from the spreadsheet content, use

```
$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,false,true);
```

instead of

```
$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Then manually convert the raw timestamp date values from cells to the format you need for the database

```
$dateofbirth = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"])
    ->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: no success on this too. The date being stored as 0000-00-00 for all records now. do I need to remove any line after doing these changes?

Comment: Do some basic debugging then..... look at the value that is actually being read from the file..... debugging should be the first step for any developer when trying to solve a problem.... but if you're getting invalid dates from that code, then what's in the cell isn't a date, just some string value

Comment: But if that code doesn't work, then what you're getting back from the cell is not a date.... we can't see what you're actually getting, only you can see it (unless you actually share)

Comment: Woah !! It worked. I just removed my explode() and then the array getting stored in $dob. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Yes, you didn't want to do any of your own date conversion code, those lines I posted give you the date ready-formatted for the database